# Count number of observations per distinct group inside summarise with dplyr (n_distinct equivalent?)

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a function that counts the number of observations within unique groups and not the number of distinct groups as `n_distinct()` does?

I'm summarising data with `dplyr` and `group_by()`, and I'm trying to calculate means of numbers of observations per a different grouping variable.

```
df<-data.frame(id=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C','C','C'),
               id.2=c('1', '2', '2', '1','1','1','2','2'),
               v=c(sample(1:10, 8)))

df%>%
  group_by(id.2)%>%
  summarise(n.mean=mean(n_distinct(id)),
            v.mean=mean(v))

# A tibble: 2 × 3
  id.2  n.mean v.mean
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 1          3    5  
2 2          2    4.5
```

What I instead need:

```
id.2  n.mean v.mean
1          1    5  
2          2    4.5
```

because for
id.2==1 n.mean is the mean of 1 observation for A, 2 for B, 1 observation for C,

```
> mean(1,2,1)
[1] 1
```

id.2==2 n.mean is the mean of 2 observations for A, 0 for B, 2 for C,

```
mean(2,0,2)
[1] 2
```

I tried grouping by `group_by(id, id.2)` first to count the observations and then pass those counts on when grouping by only id.2 in a subsequent step, but that didn't work (though I probably just don't know how to implement this with dplyr as I'm not very experienced with tidyverse solutions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `mean` correctly. `mean(1, 2, 1)` ignores all but the first argument and therefore will return 1 no matter what other numbers are in the second and third positions. For `id.2 == 1`, you'd want `mean(c(1, 2, 1))`, which returns 1.333.

We can use `table` to quickly calculate the frequencies of `id` within each grouping of `id.2`, and then take the mean of those. We can compute `v.mean` in the same step.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(id.2) %>% 
  summarize(
    n.mean = mean(table(id)),
    v.mean = mean(v)
  ) 

  id.2  n.mean v.mean
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 1       1.33   4.25
2 2       2      6
```

Your example notes that `id.2 == 2` does not have any values for `id == B`. It is not clear whether your desired solution counts this as a zero-length category, or simply ignores it. The solution above ignores it. The following includes it as a zero-length category by first `complete`-ing the input data (note new row #7, which has NA data):

```
df_complete <- complete(df, id.2, id)

  id.2  id        v
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1 1     A         9
2 1     B         1
3 1     B         2
4 1     C         5
5 2     A         4
6 2     A         7
7 2     B        NA
8 2     C         3
9 2     C        10
```

We can convert `id` to factor data, which will force `table` to preserve its unique levels even in groupings of zero length:

```
df_complete %>% 
  group_by(id.2) %>% 
  mutate(id = factor(id)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(v)) %>% 
  summarize(
    n.mean = mean(table(id)),
    v.mean = mean(v, na.rm = T)
  )

  id.2  n.mean v.mean
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 1       1.33   4.25
2 2       1.33   6
```

Or an alternate recipe that does not rely on `table`:

```
df_complete %>% 
  group_by(id.2, id) %>% 
  summarize(
    n_rows = sum(!is.na(v)), 
    id_mean = mean(v)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(id.2) %>% 
  summarize(
    n.mean = mean(n_rows),
    v.mean = weighted.mean(id_mean, n_rows, na.rm = T)
  )

  id.2  n.mean v.mean
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 1       1.33   4.25
2 2       1.33   6
```

Note that when providing randomized example data, you should use `set.seed` to control the randomization and ensure reproducibility. Here is what I used:

```
set.seed(0)
df<-data.frame(id=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C','C','C'),
               id.2=c('1', '2', '2', '1','1','1','2','2'),
               v=c(sample(1:10, 8)))
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll play around with this! I thinkweighted.mean is what I was looking for when trying to do a two-step approach. Are there equivalents for median and sd? I didn't know about table(), neat! (and yes, I totally forgot about c() while trying to produce a minimally reproducable example, thanks for catching that)

Comment: I suspect your second approach won't work for my needs (median) but it is a very nice solution. My actual dataset is much larger, of course, so I'm wondering whether  it is possible to adapt it so the ```complete()``` function is applied before using ```table()``` to include cases with 0 observations?

Comment: See edit. It is possible to convert `id` to factor before using `table`, which will preserve zero-length levels of `id`.